# WCF Service 404 on custom endpoint address

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-404

I can browse the webservice url and it shows fine in the browser.

I can get the `?wsdl` from the web browser.

When I access the service I get a 404 (fiddler says: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

The *.svclog is written to when I access the adress with a browser, but not when I access it with the soap client.

```
using (ImportServiceClient client = 
    new ImportServiceClient("ImportServiceSoap12", REMOTE_ADDRESS))
{
```

I've been trying baseAddresses and WCFExtras wsdlExtensions.
Still the same 404.
I've been looking at this: http://www.jamesgoodfellow.com/blog/post/IIS-60---HTTP-404---File-not-found-Internet-Information-Services.aspx but since it's an XP that folder doesn't exist, and it does work in the web browser, and the *.svclog is generated.

The test computer I'm trying to get this thing running on is an XP.
The computer is accessed by a no-ip address.

Before WCF I'd solved this by via, but I can't seem to find the solution in WCF.

**UPDATE**

When doing a "Configure service reference" to that endpoint, I could observe something interesting from fiddler:

/IntegrationServer/ImportService.svc returns 404
/IntegrationServer/ImportService.svc/mex returns 200
/IntegrationServer/ImportService.svc?wdsl returns 200

**UPDATE 2**

It seems that
/IntegrationServer/ImportService.svc/soap
/IntegrationServer/ImportService.svc/soap12
also works. This is my endpoint config.

```
<endpoint name="ImportServiceSoap" behaviorConfiguration="NoIpConfiguration" address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Integration.Server.IImportService"/>
<endpoint name="ImportServiceSoap12" behaviorConfiguration="NoIpConfiguration" address="soap12" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Integration.Server.IImportService">
```

Is it a correct assumption that I always must add the "address" property to the service address if I wish to use a custom endpoint address in the client?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry for that question. I somehow deleted part of the sentence. I'm just asking what request / URL / HTTP method doesn't work at the moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for a custom endpoint address you'll need to configure the address attribute in the endpoint element.

Without seeing the service web.config serviceModel element contents, I'm guessing that the service is configured to provide two metadata endpoints (...?wsdl) and (.../mex). Your UPDATE 2 changes work because of the way the endpoint config displayed in your question is configured (address="soap"). [Here is a good explanation of addressing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx)  in WCF from MSDN.